# Code converting error occurs using GCC 7.3.0

Tags: c++, gcc

Bit shifting error occurs using GCC 7.3.0

```
In file included from show_factory.h:21:0,
                 from show.h:21,
                 from main.cpp:27:
common.h: In member function ‘bool tfs::tools::ServerInfo::operator<<(std::ostream&) const’:
common.h:173:22: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ to ‘bool’ in return
         return os << server_id_;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:630: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

How to change the code here to make it safe and sound?

In the older version (<=5) of GCC, this should compile fine (according to their repo https://github.com/yage99/tfs ).
Is it a new feature for GCC 7.3.0?

Comment: What was the code to begin with?

Comment: What does this have to do with bit shifting?

Comment: Sorry, too much python

Comment: That's very odd to return a `bool` instead of a `std::ostream&` for `operator<<` used for output streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ostream`'s conversion to `bool` is marked `explicit` since C++11.  Explicit conversions aren't considered in `return` statements; you need an explicit cast.

---

As a side note: the return type for `operator<<` overloads used to insert into a stream is traditionally `std::ostream&`.  This allows insertions to be chained, such as `std::cout << foo << bar`.  Your `operator<<` overload should also generally be a free function rather than a member.  A member doesn't allow for the standard `stream << object` syntax.